# How to get an object's fields?

Tags: python, django, database, orm

I'm making a function to convert a model object into a dictionary (and all `foreignkeys` into more dictionaries, recursively). I learned from a friend that I can get a model's fields by looking at `obj._meta.fields`, but I can't find documentation for this anywhere.

How do I get a model's fields? How can I interpret what one can find in the `_meta` class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seemed fairly interesting, so I went looking through the django.forms source, looking specifically for the ModelForm implementation. I figured a ModelForm would be quite good at introspecting a given instance, and it just so happens that there is a handy function available that may help you on your way.

```
>>> from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
>>> g = Group.objects.filter()[0]
>>> d = model_to_dict(g)
>>> d
{'permissions': [40, 41, 42, 46, 47, 48, 50, 43, 44, 45, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39], 'id': 1, 'name': u'Managers'}
>>>
```

Understandably, the `_meta` attribute is undocumented because it *is* an internal implementation detail. I can't see it changing any time soon though, so it's probably relatively safe to use. You can probably use the `model_to_dict` function above as a starter for doing what you want to do. There shouldn't be much of a change. Be wary of reverse relations if you plan on recursively including models.

There may be another avenue you wish to investigate also. `django-piston` is a RESTful framework that declares several `emitters` that may be useful to you, particularly the `BaseEmitter.construct()` method. You should be able to quite easily define a `DictionaryEmitter` that you use for purposes other than RESTful serialization.

Comment: oh nice, `model_to_dict` is basically what my func was doing (i calld it `objectToDict`.. ill just try that. EDIT: ah, it doesn't follow foreignekys, which i want mine to do. i guess i can call that and look at its fields, but i already wrote it with `_meta` fields so i dnno. thanks for the tip on catching cycles, i made my func take care of that (if it already saw an object it just uses its result in-place instead of recurring)

Comment: No, it doesn't follow FKs, but you can do a replace on each foreign_key_id with a model_to_dict recursively. Since you've already got it working, no worries. Like I mentioned, the model_to_dict could be used as a starter, and adapted accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

[There's some docs on it](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/), but mostly we tend to find uses for django functions that are used internally, like `_meta.fields` or `_meta.get_all_field_names()`, `_meta.get_field_by_name`.

For me, these are best discovered via iPython and tab completion. Or the source.

Comment: +1 - The documentation for this (and a bunch of other object methods) is quite lacking.  The dir function has been my best friend as far as things like this so keep using it.  I've found it one of the best learning tools since I started coding in Django

Comment: yea the trifecta of `dir`, `help`, and the interactive cmd line are some o the biggest reasons i like python